# How can I find out if there is a Object In array within Collection with _id and after that remove it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I'm creating simple CMS, you are able to create Pages and Subpages.
You are able to delete Page like this:

```
Page.findByIdAndRemove(req.body.id, function (err, page) {
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Pagina "' + page.name_nl + '" werd verdwijderd');
    res.redirect('/pages')
});
```

The Schema of this Page Modal look look like that:

```
PageSchema.add({
    name_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name_nl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug_en:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    slug_nl:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    content_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content_nl:  {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    visible: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 1
    },
    is_headMenu: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
        default: 0
    },
    is_footerMenu: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
        default: 0
    },
    subPages: [
        PageSchema
    ],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});
```

So now I have a list of pages and also subpages in my CMS, how can I search if subpage with   _id: xxx exist and if so remove this object from array? 
My Collection look fot example like that:
 [image]

Added Json:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5853d7145471c7499536445d"),
    "name_en" : "HAHAHA",
    "name_nl" : "xDDDDD",
    "content_en" : "<p>Easy (and free!) You should check out our premium features.</p>",
    "content_nl" : "<p>Easy (and free!) You should check out our premium features.</p>",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T11:59:16.271Z"),
    "subPages" : [ 
        {
            "content_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "content_en" : "xDDDD",
            "slug_nl" : "X",
            "slug_en" : "X",
            "name_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "name_en" : "xDDDD",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T12:12:40.414Z"),
            "subPages" : [],
            "is_footerMenu" : 0,
            "is_headMenu" : 0,
            "visible" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5853da38c5a84c60950926c8")
        }, 
        {
            "content_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "content_en" : "xDDDD",
            "slug_nl" : "X",
            "slug_en" : "X",
            "name_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "name_en" : "xDDDD",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T12:14:51.920Z"),
            "subPages" : [],
            "is_footerMenu" : 0,
            "is_headMenu" : 0,
            "visible" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5853dabbddb010601991f050")
        }, 
        {
            "content_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "content_en" : "xDDDD",
            "slug_nl" : "X",
            "slug_en" : "X",
            "name_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "name_en" : "xDDDD",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T12:16:35.743Z"),
            "subPages" : [],
            "is_footerMenu" : 0,
            "is_headMenu" : 0,
            "visible" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5853db23ddb010601991f051")
        }, 
        {
            "content_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "content_en" : "xDDDD",
            "slug_nl" : "X",
            "slug_en" : "X",
            "name_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "name_en" : "xDDDD",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T12:21:58.073Z"),
            "subPages" : [],
            "is_footerMenu" : 0,
            "is_headMenu" : 0,
            "visible" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5853dc666cacf23ee9c9d378")
        }, 
        {
            "content_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "content_en" : "xDDDD",
            "slug_nl" : "X",
            "slug_en" : "X",
            "name_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "name_en" : "xDDDD",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T12:22:53.546Z"),
            "subPages" : [],
            "is_footerMenu" : 0,
            "is_headMenu" : 0,
            "visible" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5853dc9d3a2a915925b11879")
        }, 
        {
            "content_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "content_en" : "xDDDD",
            "slug_nl" : "X",
            "slug_en" : "X",
            "name_nl" : "xDDDD",
            "name_en" : "xDDDD",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T12:24:05.441Z"),
            "subPages" : [],
            "is_footerMenu" : 0,
            "is_headMenu" : 0,
            "visible" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5853dce57f27b354256228e0")
        }
    ],
    "is_footerMenu" : 1,
    "is_headMenu" : 0,
    "visible" : 1,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Please add the sample document in the question. Can't copy the json from screenshot for testing to suggest any potential solution.

Comment: Hallo here you go

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928354/mongodb-remove-subdocument-from-document

Comment: I'm using moongose