# What does 1 mean in { $unset : { field : 1} }

Tags: mongodb

In the following snippet, I am able to remove two key fields from a 
collection with different parameters (i.e. One is 1 and the other is 0).

```
> i = { name : 'name', age : 25, gender : 'female' };
{ "name" : "name", "age" : 25, "gender" : "female" }
> db.users.insert(i)
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8b5b5e654f46ccc304e44e"), 
  "name" : "name", "age" : 25, "gender" : "female" }
> db.users.update({ name : 'name'}, 
                  {$unset : {age : 1, gender : 0}}) // check here
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8b5b5e654f46ccc304e44e"), "name" : "name" }
>
```

Reference: MongoDB [$unset](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24unset)

Question> What is the usage of **1** in the following manual?

> { $unset : { field : 1} }

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB : Update Modifier semantics of "$unset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327893/mongodb-update-modifier-semantics-of-unset)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, this is simply due to JSON/BSON syntax. There has to be a value, but it doesn't matter what the value is. In the MondoDB documentation they typically use 1.

[MongoDB : Update Modifier semantics of "$unset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327893/mongodb-update-modifier-semantics-of-unset)